# nested addClass appears to not be working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

https://jsfiddle.net/qco1duyL/

I am making a hover effect occur only if the page is scrolled all of the way to the top. I tried using .css and it was not working so I tried to use addClass instead. still it is not working. If you need to see my full code let me know but this is all that relates to it besides the html for the li.

JQuery

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if($(document).scrollTop() === 0) {
    $('header').css("background-color", "rgba(18, 79, 255, 1)");
    $('.gall').show();
    $('li').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("hovered");
    } function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hovered");
    });
} else {
    $('header').css("background-color", "rgba(18, 79, 255, .5)");
    $('.gall').hide();

}});
```

CSS

```
.hovered {
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #AB5F1D,
                 2px 2px 2px #D67521,
                 3px 3px 2px #4A2A0F,
                 4px 4px 0px #000;
    color: #FF8B24;
    -webkit-text-stroke: .3px black;
}
```

Comment: could you please include your html code as well?

Comment: You're missing a comma (`,`) between the 2 functions passed to `hover()`

Comment: why are you rebinding `.hover` every time the `scroll` callback gets fired? Seems like it could cause issues.

Comment: Instead of having your hover have two functions, just toggle the class - http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: I don't imagine you actually want to bind new handlers every time a person scrolls to the top. I'd think you'd want your `.hover()` handlers (or at least the first one) to check to see if the document is at the top before adding the class..

Comment: How do I fix the handler problem so it doesn't change when you scroll to top?

Comment: Added fiddle link to full code

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if($(document).scrollTop() === 0) {
    $('header').css("background-color", "rgba(18, 79, 255, 1)");
    $('.gall').show();

} else {
    $('header').css("background-color", "rgba(18, 79, 255, .5)");
    $('.gall').hide();
}});

$('li').hover(function() {
    if($(document).scrollTop() === 0) {
        $(this).toggleClass("hovered");
} else {
    $(this).toggleClass("scrolledHovered");
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget a **,**

See jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qco1duyL/1/

```
$('li').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("hovered");
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hovered");
    });
```

Hope that helps